# Generate a bar graph if a condition is true for a category using a loop

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, categorical-data

I'm trying to create a loop to print, from a dataframe, a bar graph if a condition is true for a category (for example, category Never> 30%)

Each column represents an answer to a categorical question:

Question2
Never
Never
Very frequently
Some times
...

All I have achieved is to create a loop that prints the bar graph for each column using

```py
data [column].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind = 'barh')
```

But I do not see how to include the condition   the condition Never> 30%

Any clue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I hope that with this rewriting the question is now clearer.